# Node.js - static files are getting replaced with HTML code

Tags: node.js, express, server-side

## Problem

I just started out with Node.js my plan was to first set up a Server with some basic HTML and static files(css,js).

But when i try to Serve the static files with express.js or even without express **the js/css code is getting replaced from my index.html code.** Without Node.js everything seems to work fine i even tried it with flask in python which worked fine too.

Are there any common reasons for this?

### Node.js code

```js
    var http = require("http");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var express = require("express");

    var app = express();
    app.use("/", express.static("public"));

    http
      .createServer(function(req, res) {
        fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            return res.end("404 Not Found");
          }
          res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
          res.write(data);
          return res.end();
        });
      })
      .listen(8080);
```

### Pictures

[image: css file replaced by index.html]

[image: network aktivity]

Comment: sorry for unsharp images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So even though you are using `express` to serve static files, you are not using `express` as server instead of that you are making a manual server which serves `index.html` for EVERY request.

```
http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile("index.html"....);
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

What this code means is **create a server, and for each request read the `index.html` file and serve this**

So when the request is `http://localhost:8080/css.css` it doesn't discriminate.

I would recommend reading about creating servers in node a little more. But the solution is use express as server.

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require("fs");
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use("/", express.static("public"));

app.listen(8080, ()=>{
    console.log('Server started');
})
```

This will work just fine **GIVEN that index.html IS IN A FOLDER NAMED PUBLIC**

From the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html),

> For example, use the following code to serve images, CSS files, and
>   JavaScript files **in a directory named public**:
>
> `app.use(express.static('public'))`
>
> Now, you can load the files that are
>   in the public directory:

Note, if your files are in your project root you can use:

```
app.use("/", express.static("."));
```